# How can I JSON.stringify my SELECT values in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

```
WITH DATA AS (
  SELECT id, foo, bar
  FROM foobars
  WHERE id = 99
)

SELECT
  CONCAT('item_', CAST(id AS VARCHAR)) AS key,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    MAP(
      ARRAY[
        'id',
        'foo',
        'bar'
      ],
      ARRAY[
        CAST(id AS VARCHAR),
        CAST(foo AS VARCHAR),
        CAST(bar AS VARCHAR)
      ]
    )
  ) AS value
  FROM DATA;
```

This formats two columns, key and value. 
The value resembles a JSON-stringified object.

```
'key', 'value'
'item_99', '{"id": "99", "foo", "a", "bar": "b"}'
```

This is convenient because you can write this to cache as a string and read the value straight into a JSON.parse function call.

Two issues:

- It is a bit limiting to have to CAST everything to VARCHAR.
- I cannot figure out how to format a column as an ARRAY of MAPs.

Is there a JSON.stringify for an array of maps in Presto?

Comment: Did you solve this? SO clearly failed to..